# Access variables set in setup.cfg

Tags: python, distutils

I'm using distutils, and parts of my setup.py pulls a remote repository. I would like to be able to set the URL to this repository in the setup.cfg, but how do I access it from within setup.py?

Let's say that I have this in my setup.cfg:

```
[download]
repository = 'git://github.com/repo.git'
```

How would I access the repository variable from outside the cfg file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ConfigParser`

import ConfigParser

```
Config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()

cfg = open('abcd.txt', 'r')
Config.readfp(cfg)
cfg.close()

cfg = open('abcd.txt', 'w')
Config.remove_option('download', 'repository')
Config.set('download','repository', 'Some URL')
Config.write(cfg)
cfg.close()
```

Update: Sorry I had thought you wanted to read the value and no set it. Note that this also assumes that setup.cfg aleady exists and there's a download option already